# Jquery select :contains text with html symbols

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have some data in table like "< n/a>", and i need to get it by text in div, but don`t find how.

```
<div class="one">red</div>
<div class="one">green</div>
<div class="one"><n/a></div>

$("div.one:contains('<n/a>')")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think the problem is the selector, it is the html, you might have to escape the `<` and `>` like

```
<div class="one">&lt;n/a&gt;</div>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4ybd6/)

---

Your html renders the content `<n/a>` as html elements... see the difference between the escaped version and non escaped version

[image]

Comment: +1, though this has nothing to do with escaping, rather replacing invalid characters with its corresponding character entity.